# Portable air conditioning

Tags: air-conditioning, ventilation

I'm looking to get some air conditioning sorted for the flat for the hot summer months, something portable that I can store in the winter.

There are two outputs/wastes from an air conditioner: water + hot air. Water can be captured in the device or some sort of tray however I am struggling with what to do for the exhaust of hot air.

It's a ground floor flat so I don't want to keep any window open. The windows do however, have trickle vents. So I am wondering if I can use the trickle vent to output the hot air or is this going to be a bad idea, because its such a small opening, will it pose a problem.

Comment: Window A/C units are not an option, I'm assuming? What is the budget for the unit? What size area are you trying to condition?

Comment: I don't want an open window for security reasons. The bedroom I wish to cool is small, perhaps 18sqm. I haven't settled on a budget yet.